# Looping Entries in Super Table, display row details

Tags: craft2, plugin-supertable

I have a Super Tables field, containing related entries:

[image: Super Table with entries rows]

I'd like to display the field name (ie 'English Links') in a template, but can't figure out how, the following outputs a string of values and if I try to add a handle to the row output I get 'Impossible to access an attribute ("handle") on a string variable'.

```
{% for row in entry.relatedArticleLinks %}
    {{ row }}
{% endfor %}
```

I really don't think this was written very well in the first place tbh, as the rows are hard coded:

```
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/3 my-1">
            <h3>English</h3>
            <ul class="list-reset">
            {% for link in entry.relatedArticleLinks.englishLinks %}
                <li><a href="{{ link.url }}" class="text-black text-sm">{{ link.title }}</a></li>    
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I'm sure there's a better way of displaying this field which would allow new rows to be displayed automatically?

Comment: What type of field is English Links? Seem like a some kind of repeatable field with a "link" and "url?"

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but it does require additional calls to query this information. It might be more efficient to hard-code this text in your template, unless you really want to make this text dynamic.

There's two concepts here. When you call `entry.relatedArticleLinks` you're fetching Super Table blocks that are related to the entry in question. Calling `englishLinks` on each of these blocks will return the **content** for this field - nothing about the field definition itself, such as the handle, name, or settings - just the content.

What type of field is `englishLinks`?

If you wanted to grab the field definition as well, you can by calling:

```
{% set field = craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('relatedArticleLinks') %}
{% set blocks = craft.superTable.getSuperTableBlocks(field.id) %}
{% set fields = blocks[0].getFields() %}

{{ fields.englishLinks.name }}
```